# Inject CSS in an HTTPS iframe Podio webform

Tags: css, forms, iframe, https, podio

So, I'm trying to inject some CSS in a Podio webform `iframe`. I know that with a HTTP iframe, it's possible with `content()` from jQuery. But it's a HTTPS `iframe` here, so, it doesn't work.

I know we can add some CSS direct in the admin of Podio, but, first, I don't have access to that admin and second, the same form is use at multiple place, so, different styles should be applied...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the same origin policy you won't be able to inject your own content into the iframe from a different domain. You have to use the CSS feature inside Podio to change the look of your webforms.